# Combinatorics and Tiling

Tags: combinatorics

I need help to find a formula that works to determine the number of ways a rectangle of any size can be tiled given the number for n using only 2x1 tiles. For example, a 2x3 rectangle can be tiled 3 ways, a 2x4 rectangle can be tiled 5 ways, but is their an easier way to determine this with an equation? If so how?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_tiling#Counting_tilings_of_regions